# How do I prevent an iPhone background image from rotating when the device orientation changes?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, orientation

I've set `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return to YES for orientation, but I noticed as the iPhone rotates the background rotates as well which is a `UIImageView`. How do I have the background fixed so it doesn't rotate?

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to do the trick. i got everything to be fixed in landscape mode.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```